# How to classify devices into photodiodes, photodetectors and photocells?

Tags: solar-cell, photodiode, efficiency, solid-state-devices

Is there a clear differentiation between the three? For example in terms of efficiency (induced current/incident power)?

Comment: I would say that photodiodes and photocells are two different types of photodetectors.  "Photodetector" is a general term covering all light-sensitive devices.

Comment: photodiodes will produce photovoltaic power the same as photocells do, (just at a reduced level due to the smaller sensitive area)  glass encapsulated diodes (like 1N4148) will do it too (but may require high levels of illumination for this effect  to be measurable).  LEDs will also function this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of types and each has benefits and drawbacks.  The wikipedia pages have a lot of informative reading available.

Photodiodes would 'generally' be considered faster switching than photocells but photocell is not a very accurately defined term referring mostly to 'solar cells' that are intended for more output but not fast response.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodetector

Comment: Switching speed and current density... sounds right.